# Count function counting only last line of my list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Count function counting only last line of my list

```
N = int(raw_input())
cnt = []
for i in range(N):
    string = raw_input()
for j in range(1,len(string)):  
    if string[j] =='K':
        cnt.append('R')
    elif string[j] =='R':
        cnt.append('R')
if string[0] == 'k':
    cnt.append('k')
elif string[0] == 'R':
    cnt.append('R')
print cnt.count('R')
```

if I am giving the input:-

```
2
RKKRK
RKKR`
```

It is give answer of last line only
of `RKKR`

Comment: Look closely at your indentation; where do you think the `for in in range(N)` loop ends?

Comment: the string variable is over written by RKKR  and the first input RKKRK is lost, so string contains only RKKRK

Comment: yes u are right but how i slove it

Comment: make a list of strings

Comment: i think cnt is storing strings in list

Comment: How will the input be? and How do you want the output to be?  give an example

Comment: 2  RKKRK     RKKR   4 3

Comment: sry i have not describe question fully in this i have to swap R and K except first character and tell number of R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are exactly trying to achieve but if you are trying to count R and K in the string there are more elegant ways to achieve it. But for your reference I had modified your code.

```
N = int(raw_input())
s = []
for i in range(N):
    s.append(raw_input())
for string in s:
    cnt = []
    for j in range(1,len(string)):
        if string[j] =='K':
            cnt.append('R')
        elif string[j] =='R':
            cnt.append('R')
    if string[0] == 'k':
        cnt.append('k')
    elif string[0] == 'R':
        cnt.append('R')
    print cnt.count('R')
```

you had been over writing string every time you get a raw input but here i just append every input to a list then processed one by one at a time.

FYI - The following code will do the job better

```
N = int(raw_input())
s = []
for i in range(N):
    s.append(raw_input())
for string in s:
    print len(filter(lambda x: x in ("R","K"), string))
```